# Quicksort in R - array sorted after k steps

Tags: r, quicksort

I am pretty new to R, so there is definitely some improvement to my code needed. What I want is to do quicksort on an array of n elements, count the number of comparisons made and output the sorted array after k comparisons.

So far, I have reused the code for a quicksort algorithm found here:

```
quickSort <- function(arr) {

  # Pick a number at random.
  mid <- sample(arr, 1)
  print(arr)
  print(mid)

  # Place-holders for left and right values.
  left <- c()
  right <- c()

  # Move all the smaller values to the left, bigger values to the right.
  lapply(arr[arr != mid], function(d) {

    count <<- count + 1

    stopifnot(count <= k)

    if (d < mid) {
      left <<- c(left, d)
    }
    else {
      right <<- c(right, d)
    }
  })

  if (length(left) > 1) {
    left <- quickSort(left)
  }

  if (length(right) > 1) {
    right <- quickSort(right)
  }

  # Finally, return the sorted values.
  c(left, mid, right)
}
```

I am currently struggling with several things:
How can I get not only the partial vector that is currently being sorted but also the full vector?
Did I put the right stopping condition in the right place?

An example of what I want:
given an array (2,4,1,3,5) and the first pivot element 3, after four comparisons I would want the output to be (2,1,3,4,5).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: do you not want to use `sort`?

Comment: @Onyambu: To sort the array isn't a goal it itself, rather he/she wants to explore the [quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) algorithm specifically.